# How to change the location of the Gradle cache directory?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I would like to be able to change the location of the Gradle cache directory based on a system property. If it's passed in, I'd like it to override the default location, that Gradle uses. (I'm using Gradle 4.2.2 and can't upgrade to a newer version at the moment).

Unfortunately, from what I'm seeing, it doesn't seem to be possible to use system properties from within the `settings.gradle` file. Could somebody please provide an example of how this could be done and confirm whether, or not it could be done in the first place? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe something [in this documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html) can help.

Comment: Can you use environment variables?